# Opening a PDF in Visual c++

Tags: c++, forms, pdf, visual-c++

I am now using the Adobe PDF reader on a Form and am viewing PDF's with this code:

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialogx = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
openFileDialogx->ShowDialog();
axAcroPDF1->src=openFileDialogx->FileName;
```

This code is inside of a button so that when I press the button a file browser opens, and i select which file i want to view.

How can i automatically opening the PDF immediately after pressing the button so that I do not have to manually browse and select the PDF file?

Comment: If you know which specific PDF file to open already, why do you need the `OpenFileDialog`? is this some flaw in your class design?

Comment: so how can i do it ?? i mean the code because i totally new in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openFileDialogx->FileName;
```

FileName is just a string.
If you know the path to the file, you can replace that call with a direct file path instead.

**Example:**

```
String^ Path = "file.pdf";
axAcroPDF1->src=Path;
```